# CakePHP 3.x - File validators on upload always failing

Tags: file, validation, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-3.0

I am working on an image upload. I am trying to do the image verification in the model (like it should, right?), however I can't get the validation to work.

I put the following in `src/Model/Table/CommentTable`:

```
   public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
   {
       //...
       $validator->add('photofile', 'upload', [
           'rule' => ['uploadedFile', ['maxSize' => 1048576, 'optional' => true, 'types' => ['image/*']]],
           'message' => 'Not a valid file'
       ]);

       //...
    }
```

For testing my controller looks like (I hard-coded an existing file):

```
    $comment = $this->Comments->newEntity([
        'body' => $data['body'],
        'bin_id' => $bin_id,
        'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
        'photofile' => 'C:/Users/Robert/Downloads/test.jpg'
    ]);
```

This file is only a couple of bytes, yet after debugging `$comment` is shows an error in 'photofile':

```
'[errors]' => [
    'photofile' => [
        'upload' => 'Not a valid file'
    ]
],
```

So why is the validator always failing? Am I using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not an uploaded file, so that's generally the expected behavior. Also a string isn't supported as a valid value at all, the value must either be a file upload array, or as of CakePHP 3.4, an object that implements `\Psr\Http\Message\UploadedFileInterface`.

For file upload arrays, the `uploadedFile` validation rule provided by CakePHP will utilize [**`is_uploaded_file()`**](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file), which will fail for files that haven't actually been uploaded, and you cannot emulate them.

As of CakePHP 3.4 you can use `UploadedFileInterface` objects as already mentioned. CakePHP requires `\Zend\Diactoros\UploadedFile` which provides an implementation that you could utilize for testing purposes, like:

```
$file = 'C:/Users/Robert/Downloads/test.jpg';

$comment = $this->Comments->newEntity([
    'body' => $data['body'],
    'bin_id' => $bin_id,
    'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
    'photofile' => new \Zend\Diactoros\UploadedFile(
        $file,
        filesize($file),
        \UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
        pathinfo($file, \PATHINFO_BASENAME),
        'image/jpeg'
    )
]);
```

However while this will pass validation, you won't be able to move that file using `UploadedFile::moveTo()`, as it uses **[`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)**, which again only works with files that have actually been uploaded.

Also regex validation of MIME types only works when passed as a string (this currently isn't documented), and it must be a valid regex including delimiters, like

```
'types' => '#^image/.+$#'
```

Alternatively specify the exact types as an array, ie

```
'types' => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', /* ... */]
```

See also

- **[Zend Diactoros API > UploadedFile](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-diactoros/api/#uploadedfile)**
- **[CakePHP API > \Cake\Validation\Validation::uploadedFile()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_uploadedFile)**

Comment: Very clear answer. I decided to use the `fileSize()` and `mimeType()` validators instead as they produce more helpful errors. Your advice is still applicable to both.